# How to write css for parent class based on child class?

Tags: html, css

I want to add `CSS` only for `listing-system` class but child class of "`expired`". How i am struggling to write `CSS` for it, can anyone help me. Thanks

```
<div class="listing-system">
    <div class="listing-system-row">
        <div class="listing-system-row-image">
            <a href="#" style="background-image: url('#')">
                <div class="ribbon expired">
                    Expired                                 
                </div><!-- /.ribbon -->
            </a>
        </div><!-- /.listing-system-row-image -->
    </div><!-- /.listing-system-row-actions -->
</div><!-- /.listing-system-row -->

<div class="listing-system">
    <div class="listing-system-row">
        <div class="listing-system-row-image">
            <a href="#" style="background-image: url('#')">
                <div class="ribbon">
                    Pending                                 
                </div><!-- /.ribbon -->
            </a>
        </div><!-- /.listing-system-row-image -->
    </div><!-- /.listing-system-row-actions -->
</div><!-- /.listing-system-row --
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: `:has` selector is depricated in css3 , so you can's select parent class based on child class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this is working too

```
$(".ribbon.expired") .parentsUntil( ".listing-system" ) .css( "display", "none" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Jquery, If you want to select a class '.listing-system' which has a child class '.ribbon.expired',

```
$('.ribbon.expired').closest('.listing-system').css('your css style goes here');
```

Comment: Or better: `$('.ribbon.expired').closest('.listing-system').addClass('has-ribbon');` then add your styles to the `has-ribbon` class in CSS.